# dd if=/dev/random is 'randomly' bottlenecked with BIG time lags, but I have no idea why

Tags: performance, random

I get **wildly** different `real times` when I run the following command.

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1k count=1
```

It doesn' happen for `if=/dev/null`, nor does it happen for `if=/dev/urandom`

I've run it 500 times. Here are the general stats (per call). The times are in seconds.

```
Minimum   Maximum  Average   Median
00.002    89.999   4.50402   2.275
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about why this may be happening?
The system is Ubuntu 10.04 desktop. Bash version is 4.1.5(1)
It also shows the similar wild fluctuations in a VirtualBox VM running the same version of Ubuntu.

---

Here is the actual test code

```
cp /dev/null "$HOME/dd-random.secs" 
for ((i=100;i<=500;i++)); do
    if   ((i<10))  ;then zi="00$i"
    elif ((i<100)) ;then zi="0$i"
    else                 zi="$i"
    fi 
    echo -ne "$zi\t" >>"$HOME/dd-random.secs"
    exec 3>/dev/null 4>/dev/null
        { time { dd if=/dev/random bs=1k count=1; } 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 |tail -n 3|tr 'm\n' '\t' |sed -re "s/([0-9])s/\1/g" >>"$HOME/dd-random.secs" 
    exec 3>&- 4>&-
    echo >>"$HOME/dd-random.secs"
done
```

Comment: Regarding the difference between `/dev/random` and `/dev/random`, I highly recommend reading [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939) (“The short answer is yes. The long answer is also yes.”).

Comment: A minor remark: do not use `/dev/null` for reading - it is a **sink**, not a **source**. For empty (zero) input, use `/dev/zero`.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz the purpose of copying /dev/null is not to create a endlessly big file filled with zeros but to generate an empty file. So `/dev/null` can be a source (immediately returning EOF) and is the right one here. However using `: > ~/did-random.secs` is a clearer way to create or truncate a file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's exactly the difference between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` -- `random` uses the entropy pool, which gathers noise from a bunch of sources and keeps track of "how much" noise is currently in the pool, so `random` knows how much high-quality randomness it can generate. Since the entropy pool has a finite amount of noise, reading from `random` might need to block if there isn't enough entropy available. `urandom` never blocks, but you might get "less random" data from it.

From the `random(4)` man page:

> When read, the /dev/random device will only return random bytes within the estimated number of  bits of noise in the entropy pool. /dev/random should be suitable for uses that need very high quality randomness such as one-time pad or key generation. When the entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block until additional environmental noise is gathered.
>
> A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for more entropy.  As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I actually thought that urandom was the more random (slower) one, so its good to have that cleared up *`/dev/random`* is the more random.... There is absolutely no way I would ever have thought that it could/would be **that much** slower... Just that point alone (90 seconds) implies some serious design intent...  I don't know how the entropy is established, but I assume it is related to real-time system activity...

Comment: @fred Reading continuously from `/dev/random` will consume it really fast; normally apps are only reading small amounts. You can check `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` to see how much entropy is currently available (in bits)

Comment: @fred: The short answer is that you don't use `/dev/random`. The long answer is [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939). @Michael: I kind of object to “guarantees the output will actually be random”, which is true only for a very particular definition of random which is neither practically nor theoretically useful.

Comment: @Michael: Why, if I repeatedly cat `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, does the number keep dropping?

Comment: @Faheem The number should be fluctuating continuously as the entropy pool changes; it can't actually keep dropping or it would hit 0 and stay there

Comment: @Michael: Ok. Then I guess it was just a coincidence that it seemed to be dropping. Thanks.

Comment: @Faheem. I used a for-loop to cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail (after fast manual tests)... I observed that it drops (I assume that's because once that particular "part" of the available entropy has be accessed, it is no longer random, because it is now known) It doesn't go below 130/140 and recovers in "reasonable* time... My comment about the reason for the dropping is assumption.. I probably should have phrased it as a question)  so if  I'm wrong please let me know (someone..anyone...

Comment: @fred: Does the system actually need to "access" the entropy in order to count the amount of entropy? That seems...odd. I tried it again, and it does drop steadily till around below 200, then it fluctuates, but does not go below 130 or so. There must be some explanation for this.

Comment: @Faheem It shouldn't need to, it should have the count stored separately so it knows how much of the pool is actually available to use. The entropy is probably falling because you've stopped using your computer and are just staring at a terminal window for a long period of time

Comment: @Michael: Well not that long.:-) And it drops quite fast. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Faheem Yes, but mine is always pretty low for some reason (around 150)

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux:

"When the entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block until additional environmental noise is gathered."

Edit:  Looks like Michael beat me to it!

Comment: Aha! thanks... so my bright idea of stopping whatever I could so as to not interfere with the test wasn't so bright after all :)...  As soon as I saw the words 'entropy pool', it all made sense... I'd better read the link now...